# EntityFramework wants to delete a table from my data model that is very clearly in the database. Any ideas why?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am attempting to update my EntityFramework data model from a SQL 2008 database to add a couple new tables. There are at least 100 other tables in the model and they are all fine and slated to be refreshed, but EF keeps insisting that this one table does not exist in the database, even though I am looking right at it and can select from it, and adds it to the "Delete" list. The connection string is correct and the columns inside the table match what is currently there. Any idea why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is the mapping correct? For example, does EF think the entity for `Animal` points to table called `Animals`?

Comment: How are you using EF? Are you using code-first? Are you using EF migrations?

Comment: Permissions? If it can't see the table or doesn't have view definition on it then that can happen.

Comment: Jonathan Allen, thank you! Someone had set explicit permissions on just this one table that were apparently preventing EF from working with it!